# How is *p1->p2 and *p1.a interpreted in c?

Tags: c, syntax

This seems ambiguous to me:

```
*p1->p2
    *(p1->p2) or (*p1)->p2

*p1.a
    *(p1.a) or (*p1).a
```

How does the compiler interpret such expressions?

Comment: Using [Operator Precedence](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's all down to [*operator precedence*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence).  Both `->` and `.` have higher precedence than `*` (in this context), so the two expressions are equivalent to:

```
*(p1->p2)
*(p1.a)
```

Answer (score 2):

The arrow (`->`) and dot (`.`) has higher precedence than the dereference operator (`*`) so it would be parsed as:

```
*(p1->p2)
*(p1.a)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) p1 is pointer to struct that contains p2, and p2 is pointer to something that you de-reference. *(p1->p2)
2) p1 is variable (not pointer) to struct that contains a, a is pointer that you de-reference. *(p1.a)

for more see [C Operator Precedence and Associativity](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)