# Confused by double pointer traversal of linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So I was watching this Ted Talk w/ Linus Torvalds wherein he outlines this example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8NPllzkFhE&t=14m26s

I was intrigued by it, so I wanted to code it up for myself:

```
void remove_node(node* entry) {
  node** indirect = &head;

  while (*indirect != entry) {
    indirect = &(*indirect)->next;
  }

  *indirect = entry->next;

  free(entry);
}
```

I understand almost all of it, but I am deeply confused by this line:

```
indirect = &(*indirect)->next;
```

The `&(*indirect)` seems to take the address of dereferencing `indirect`, which I would think would cancel each other out and we just end up with plain `indirect` again. Although that is obviously incorrect, I do not exactly understand why.

If that is not correct (which it isn't), maybe I am just not understanding the grouping/order of operations properly when `->` is involved. However, no matter how I try to separate it out, it does not work the same:

```
node* blegh;
while (*indirect != entry) {
  // Doesn't work.
  blegh = (*indirect)->next;
  indirect = &blegh;
}
```

If someone could help me wrap my feeble brain around this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is \*p1->p2 and \*p1.a interpreted in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246509/how-is-p1-p2-and-p1-a-interpreted-in-c)

Comment: Postfix operators (including arrow `->`, dot `.` and brackets `[]`) in C all have higher precedence than prefix operators (including `*` and `&`). See [Operator Precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)

Comment: @4386427 It seems to be working when I test it... Can you show how it's wrong?

Comment: @JacksonLenhart Just forget my previous comment. It was wrong and I have deleted it.

Comment: you have missed the evaluation order.  `&(*indirect)->next` is not `(&(*indirect))->next`, but `&((*indirect)->next)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand the line:

```
indirect = &(*indirect)->next;
```

you need to understand the precedence of the operators, i.e. understand in which order the individual operators are executed. For instance: Is `&` executed before or after `->` ?

You can get the answer here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

It will tell you that your line is the same as:

```
indirect = &((*indirect)->next);
```

So what the code does is to get **the address of the next pointer** in the current node. Consequently `*indirect` will be the value of the next pointer (aka a pointer to the next node).

Your attempt to rewrite the code is wrong because `blegh` is not part of the list so the address of `blegh` is not part of anything in the list. However, you can do:

```
node* blegh;
while (*indirect != entry) {
  blegh = *indirect;         // Pointer to current node
  indirect = &blegh->next;   // Get address of next-pointer in current node 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
indirect = &(*indirect)->next;
```

is equavlent to

```
indirect = &((*indirect)->next);
```

So the address of the "next" element is assigned to "indirect" here.

The following doesn't work.

```
  blegh = *indirect->next;
  indirect = &blegh;
```

Because `indirect = &blegh;` is storing address of local variable "blegh" to "indirect".

Try doing the following.

```
  node* indirect = head; //Use single pointer "indirect" 

  while (indirect != entry) {
    indirect = &indirect->next; //Assign "next" pointer to "indirect"
  }
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot. But the alternative you recommend with a single pointer does not achieve the elegance of Linus' example. Wouldn't you have to use a pointer to the previous node to delete, and also have to account for the special case of deleting the head?

Comment: Firstly, I was trying to answer the question from the view of double pointer usage. But yes, you need to add a check if the entry is head, then update the head with next.